# PHP string concatenation as image watermark

Tags: php, string, image, concatenation

I have a function that successfully inserts text into an image, based on the font size, font color, text coordinates, the text string itself, and the background image. The function is working perfectly. However, I have an option to concatenate the username with some sample text, so that the string can be generated in the image. This happens in two different ways:

1.Username + Text -> this is the text to be generated in the image.
2.Text + Username -> this is the text to be generated in the image.

This is code sample for the options:

```
  //option 1
  $textValue = $username . ' ' . $textValue;


  //option 2
  $textValue = $textValue . ' ' . $username;
```

So this should be working perfectly as PHP concatenates the strings in this way (Right?)
See the results in the image below:

[image]

So you see in the first line the username is before the text and the result is perfectly fine, but in the second line the text it is messed up.
I am using PHP GD to write the text into the image. And it has nothing to do with the cyrillic characters. I have tested with cyrillic characters and the problem is the same. I have removed the actual username for the test image and replaced it with the string 'username' just to get the idea.

Comment: Check whether the length of the string makes a difference, it looks like the text just wraps around on the same line.

Comment: the length is ok, I am using the https://github.com/kus/php-image class for image manipulation. The selected area is the same size in both ways.

Comment: I mean: use a shorter string and see whether the overwrite effect disappears. If so you will have to split your string into parts that fit the length of the image and reposition the cursor lower for each part.

Comment: still not working properly.. shorter string is OK, but as the string gets longer, the text size is reduced automatically. But if the username is after the string, it aint working. Its only working if the username is in the first place..

Comment: If you add the code where you actually call the ->text() function, maybe I can help.

Comment: https://github.com/kus/php-image take a look at this class, and the ->textBox() function.. I use the same function, and the text needed for the image is included in the scope

Comment: I think your error is either in the call to ->text() or ->textBox(). That is why I can only help if I know the call.

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/ab071c1bf7.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time please put the code in the comment image in the question. It is also much easier to mark code out and for me to copy anything.

In the code you show (https://i.imgsafe.org/ab071c1bf7.png) you call `->textBox()` with both heigth, width and fontSize specified.

If you leave out the height, the code will just wrap the string for you over multiple lines, so that is one solution.

At the moment the fontSize is reduced in size by the `->fitToWidth()` function until it should fit. Either the problem is that this function works incorrectly because it does not work well with Unicode characters or because the font itself cannot be drawn at the size calculated and this is written larger.

If the problem is unicode the solution might be make sure that encoding of the two added strings is the same by using:

```
// option 1
$textValue = mb_convert_encoding($username, 'UTF-8') . 
    mb_convert_encoding(' ', 'UTF-8') . mb_convert_encoding($textValue, 'UTF-8');
```

And:

```
// option 2
$textValue = mb_convert_encoding($textValue, 'UTF-8') . 
    mb_convert_encoding(' ', 'UTF-8') . mb_convert_encoding($username, 'UTF-8');
```

Probably you can clean this code up, but the important thing is to convert the encodings before you join the string parts. PHP prior to PHP 7 does not *'know'* encoding, everything is just one long sequence of bytes for the PHP functions. Different encodings result in different sequences of bytes so you have to convert everything to the exact encoding you need.

Comment: thanks, dude, i was also looking for the ->fitToWidth() function, but in two different cases (also cyrillic) the same issue is working with the username before and after, and the encoding is not different from this case. so now I now where the problem is, but how can it be fixed?

Comment: Added a probable workaround for the encoding issue. If it is in the font file I am afraid I am out of my depth. :)

Comment: A workaround in case the problem is a mix of differently encoded strings. If that is not the problem, the workaround will not fix it.

Comment: thanks a lot, dude, i am pretty sure now it is encoding issue